# PHP variables within href tags

Tags: php, html, variables, download, href

I have many products under many categories which contain different data sheets. When a user is on the single product page I need to output the correct download link (data sheet) for that product.

```
 <?php
 $path = 'http://www.ctagroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/';
 $filename = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'File Name', true );

 echo "<a href='" $path . " " . $filename "' download>Link</a>";?>
```

I cannot seem to figure it out, please help!

Comment: you missed so many php format,should look like `echo "<a href='".$path.$filename."'/download>Link</a>";?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a few mistakes. Please try this.

```
<?php
$path = 'http://www.ctagroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/';
$filename = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'File Name', true );
echo "<a href='".$path.$filename."'/download>Link</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ali I'm quite new to php as you can see!

Comment: Call to undefined function get_post_meta() -- at line 3

Comment: No i don't use this in wordpress

Comment: @AliZia I clicked on the tick but it won't let me on the up arrow

Comment: @ctad, glad to help.

Comment: @AliZia, how can I add an image as the link in the echo?

Comment: @ctad, Set variable `$img` and then use `echo "<a href='".$path.$filename."'/download><img src=$img /></a>";?>`

Comment: @ctad, no problem mate. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Format not correct.
You could use without so many spaces.

```
echo "<a href='".$path.$filename."'/download>Link</a>";
```